# Why $T_pM$ instead of $TM_p$?

Tags: soft-question, smooth-manifolds, convention, tangent-bundle

If $E\to M$ is a fiber bundle, it's convention to write 1. $E_p$ for the fiber at $p$, 2. $E^*$ for its dual bundle.

Exceptionally, for the tangent bundle $TM\to M$ almost every author writes 1. $T_pM$ for the fiber at $p$, 2. $T^*M$ for its dual bundle, instead of $TM_p$ and $TM^*$.
Is there any reason for why this is the convention?

Comment: Some authors define tangent space (more generally fibers) after defining total space. i.e. they first define what a fiber bundle or tangent bundle is then they define tangent space to be fiber at point $p$ which agree with $TM_p$ ($E_p$) notation. Other authors define first the tangent space $T_pM$ then glue them together to construct a  tangent bundle $TM$.

Comment: I agree with the above comment but also notice how both $TM_p$ and $TM^*$ make it seem notationally like $_p$ or $^*$ refer to $M$, whereas they actually refer to $TM$. A solution is to put brackets: $(TM)^*, (TM)_p$, but that's pretty cumbersome, so you go to the other solution: pit $^*,_p$ next to $T$ instead of $M$

Comment: The tangent bundle’s name is $T$; the $M$ is a variable telling you which manifold you’re performing the tangent bundle operation on. It’s exactly like writing $f’(x)$ for the derivative.

Comment: $T_p$ can be seen as an operator at point $p,$ mapping a manifold $M$ to a vector space.